# Twig always generates required fields on Symfony2.8

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm creating a form with symfony ,and the problem it's the generated fields always are required even if I set the require properti like ''

```
  <div class='form-group'>
      {{ form_label(form.isActive,'Activo') }}
      {{ form_widget(form.isActive, { 'attr' : {'class':'checkbox', 'required':''}}) }}
      <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.isActive)}}</span>
    </div>
```

generates this code

```
<div class='form-group'>
      <label for="user_isActive" class="required">Activo</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="user_isActive" name="user[isActive]" required="required" class="checkbox" required="" value="1" />
      <span class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should set require option in FormBuilder, not in a template.

Comment: I dont set anything about required in in the builder but ,all the fileds are required

Comment: They are required by default. If you want them not to be required, set them in FormBuilder as 'required' => false

Comment: `->add('isActive','checkbox',array('required'=>'false'))` I tried with this but doesn't work,I'm looking for it on de official documentation

Comment: If you set it like this `{{ form_widget(form.isActive, { 'attr' : {'class':'checkbox'}}) }}` and '->add('isActive','checkbox',array('required'=>false)) ' it must work. Remember to put false without quatation marks. So not 'false' but false

Comment: Now works ,was the quotes

Comment: Added a response. Please mark it as correct for others to know that this questions is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave template alone regarding require option. So put it like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.isActive, { 'attr' : {'class':'checkbox'}}) }}
```

And in form builder like this:

```
->add('isActive','checkbox',array('required' => false))
```